# Initialize TextBox with the Password TextMode

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to initialize the TextBox with the Password TextMode in my C# code. I do it in Page_Load function. But after the output in a browser there is no text.

```
this.passwordTextBox.Text = this.GetData().Password;
this.confirmPasswordTextBox.Text = this.GetData().Password;
```

How can I assing a value to this property?

Comment: What does GetData() do? Can you show us the code?

Comment: @Mamta Dalal it just assigns a local variables from DB. But I already did the problem with the aid of Răzvan Panda. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the password using:

```
this.passwordTextBox.Attributes["value"] = this.GetData().Password;
```

or

```
this.passwordTextBox.Attributes.Add("value", this.GetData().Password);
```

[Setting the Value of a TextBox with TextMode=Password](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/12/18/1300.aspx)